# SQL Query Error with Pivot, Case, and Group By

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, pivot

I have a pivot query that works, but with the addition of the case statement to color code decimal values, it is splitting it into 2 rows, and I need it to be in a single row.  So I added in a `GROUP BY` and am getting syntax errors which I can't resolve.

My query that works that produces separate rows:

```
  select * from (
    select * from
  (select 
      buscat as prodline , 
      prod_parent as prodparent, 
      year_month, 
      volume, 
      load_source, 
      tstamp, 
   case 
       when (VOLUME like '%.%') 
          then 'color:#FF7755;font-weight;' 
       else 'color:#000000;' 
       end flag
from HISTORY where id>0)
pivot
     (max (volume)
     for year_month
     in ('2013-06'     as "JUN'13" ,
'2013-07'     as "JUL'13" ,
'2013-08'     as "AUG'13" ,
'2013-09'     as "SEP'13" ,
'2020-10'     as "OCT'20" ,
'2020-11'     as "NOV'20" ))
   )
    query_1, 
    (select max(id) id,prod_parent, buscat from HISTORY group by buscat,prod_parent) 
    query_2 where
     query_1.prodline=query_2.buscat 
     and query_1.prodparent=query_2.prod_parent
     and load_source = 'Soft'
       order by id;
```

The pivot by itself, with the CASE statement returns:  [Pivot ResultSet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYXbg.jpg)

As you can see, it's separated into 2 rows.  I want it to show in 1 row.

I added in Group By, my new query:

```
select * from (

select prodline, prodparent,year_month, max(volume) volume ,load_source,tstamp, 
  case when instr(max(VOLUME), '.') > 0 then 'color:#FF7755;' else 'color:#000000;' end flag from 
  (
select id, buscat as prodline , prod_parent as prodparent, year_month, volume, load_source, tstamp,
   case when instr(VOLUME, '.') > 0 then 'color:#FF7755;' else 'color:#000000;' end flag
 from HISTORY where id > 0
  )
 group by prodline, prodparent,year_month, load_source,tstamp;

pivot
     (max (volume)
     for year_month
     in ('2013-06'     as "JUN'13" ,
'2013-07'     as "JUL'13" ,
'2013-08'     as "AUG'13" ,
'2013-09'     as "SEP'13" ,
'2020-10'     as "OCT'20" ,
'2020-11'     as "NOV'20" ))
   )
query_1, (select max(id) id,prod_parent, buscat from HISTORY group by buscat,prod_parent) 
          query_2 where
     query_1.prodline=query_2.buscat 
     and query_1.prodparent=query_2.prod_parent
     and load_source = 'Soft'
         order by id;
```

Running the query with the Group By gives me an error:

```
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 13 Column: 7
```

Fixing this results in another syntax error.  The query with the `Group By` excluding the pivot runs fine separately.

This runs fine:

```
select prodline, prodparent,year_month, max(volume) volume ,load_source,tstamp, 
  case when instr(max(VOLUME), '.') > 0 then 'color:#FF7755;' else 'color:#000000;' end flag from 
  (
select id, buscat as prodline , prod_parent as prodparent, year_month, volume, load_source, tstamp,
   case when instr(VOLUME, '.') > 0 then 'color:#FF7755;' else 'color:#000000;' end flag
 from HISTORY where id > 0
  )
 group by prodline, prodparent,year_month, load_source,tstamp;
```

Am I adding the `Group By` in the right place?  How can I fix my syntax errors when I combine the pivot with the `Group By` clause?

Comment: What does this code `case when (VOLUME like '%.%') then 'color:#FF7755;font-weight;' else 'color:#000000;' end` mean? The problem is in it, what exactly do you want to colorize?

Comment: I am coloring any integers in the VOLUME field which have decimals to red. Integers which don't have decimals remain black.

Comment: But you need to colorize integers in the resulting set, right? The current query returns two rows, one - where all integers are summarized, and the second - for others.

Comment: Correct, the current query returns 2 rows, one black row (integers), one red row (decimals), hence why I was trying the GROUP by, to group by prodline, prodparent,year_month, load_source,tstamp in order to return combined rows.

Comment: If the `flag` is passed into some HTML formatting, shouldn't it be a CSS class name rather than a hardcoded colour spec?

Answer (score 1):

When you put this expression

```
case 
   when (VOLUME like '%.%') 
      then 'color:#FF7755;font-weight;' 
   else 'color:#000000;' 
   end flag
```

into inner subquery, it splits your data into two parts: integer values and non-integer values. After that the query calculates them separately and return two rows: one row for integer values and one for non-integers. As I understand, you need first to calculate, and then - highlight calculated values, so move the expression above to outer subquery. Also, you will get several columns with calculated data, and you will need to highlight each column separately (my guess).

SO, you need something like this:

```
select *
  from (select prodline, prodparent,
               "JUN'13", "JUL'13", "AUG'13", "SEP'13", "OCT'20", "NOV'20",
               case when ("JUN'13" like '%.%') then 'color:#FF7755;font-weight;' 
                            else 'color:#000000;' end flag_jun,
               case when ("JUL'13" like '%.%') then 'color:#FF7755;font-weight;' 
                            else 'color:#000000;' end flag_jul,
               ... 4 more case statements
          from (select buscat as prodline, prod_parent as prodparent, year_month, volume, 
                       load_source, tstamp                      
                   from HISTORY where id>0)
         pivot (max (volume) for year_month in ('2013-06' as "JUN'13", '2013-07' as "JUL'13",
                                                '2013-08' as "AUG'13", '2013-09' as "SEP'13",
                                                '2020-10' as "OCT'20", '2020-11' as "NOV'20"))
        ) query_1 join
       (select max(id) id, prod_parent, buscat 
          from HISTORY 
         group by buscat,prod_parent
        ) query_2 on  query_1.prodline = query_2.buscat 
                  and query_1.prodparent = query_2.prod_parent
 where load_source = 'Soft'
 order by id;
```